# Neo4j search for nodes while combining relationship types in different directions?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a starting node, and I'm supposed to find all matching nodes that can be found using 3 different relationship types.

For example: `(n1:NodeType1)-[:Use|Realisation|Aggregation]-(n2:NodeType2)`

How would I write a query that would search for `n2` using the `Use` and `Realisation` relationships in exclusively one direction, and `Aggregation` exclusively in the other? It can be any combination of the three, within 20 hops.

It should be able to cover all combinations. Examples:

```
(n1)<-[:Use]-()-[:Aggregation]->()<-[:Use]-()<-[:Realisation]-()-[:Aggregation]->(n2)

(n1)-[:Aggregation]->()-[:Aggregation]->()<-[:Use]-(n2)
```

I currently have this written:

```
MATCH (n1:`NodeType1`)<-[:`Use`|`Realisation`*0..20]-()-[`Aggregation`*0..20]->(n2:`NodeType2`)
```

With this I have a problem that after using the 'Aggregation' relationship, it doesn't check for the other two anymore. Another problem is that this could theoretically reach 40 hops, even though I want it limited to a maximum of 20.

Any help in how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: Since your maximum path length is 20, any query could take a very long time or run out of memory, depending on your data characteristics.

##### Approach 1

This query finds every path of up to length 20 using those 3 relationship types in any direction, and then filters for those in which every type points in the required direction (`Aggregation` must point right, and the others must point left).

```
MATCH p=(:NodeType1)-[:Use|Realisation|Aggregation*..20]-(:NodeType2)
WHERE ALL(i IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(p)-1) WHERE NODES(p)[i] = CASE TYPE(RELATIONSHIPS(p)[i])
  WHEN 'Aggregation' THEN
    STARTNODE(RELATIONSHIPS(p)[i])
  ELSE
    ENDNODE(RELATIONSHIPS(p)[i]) END
)
RETURN p
```

##### Approach 2

This may be faster than approach 1.

This query uses the APOC procedure [apoc.path.expandConfig](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.path/apoc.path.expandConfig/), which has special support for use cases like yours.

```
MATCH (n:NodeType1)
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(n, {
    relationshipFilter: "<Use|<Realisation|Aggregation>",
    labelFilter: ">NodeType2",
    minLevel: 1,
    maxLevel: 20
}) YIELD path
RETURN path
```

Comment: Approach 2 worked like a charm.Thank you!